# How to force webpack to generate dynamic publicPath for resources

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a MicroFrontend Host application that would be able to bootstrap one or more React applications built with webpack. For that purpose I need to force the application to load its resources from some different URL - and not just using relative paths.

Webpack has a nice feature for setting the public path: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/ However there are some limitations:

- if I don't apply it at build time then everything that is rendered in the index.html file will not have it included
- it is a global variable which makes it unusable for my case - I cannot set two different values for two different micro frontends

Is there any way to make such a public url dynamic for an application built with webpack?
I can live with the fact that I will have to manually update all urls in index.html, but then all the other resources (images, etc) I'd like to be able to get from some other URL.
This is in general similar to hosting all the resources generated by webpack on a CDN and having index.html still served from a web server with a different address.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature should be configured on your frontend server (nginx/apache/node), not webpack.
It looks like you just need a proxy configuration for it.
Example for `webpack-dev-server`, you can try something like this on `localhost`:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: [{
    {
      context: '/my/backend',
      target: `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
      pathRewrite: {'^/app1/images': '/shared/images'}
    },
    {
      context: '/my/backend',
      target: `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
      pathRewrite: {'^/app2/images': '/shared/images'}
    },
    {
      context: '/my/backend',
      target: `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
      pathRewrite: {'^/app1/sounds': '/shared/sounds'}
    },
    {
      context: '/my/backend',
      target: `${PROTOCOL}://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
      pathRewrite: {'^/app2/sounds': '/path/to/cdn'}
    }]
}
```

It is pseudocode, do not try this at home, but you got the idea.
Code and rules depends on server you choose of course.

PS. But it is very interesting question, I will try to find some solution with `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup with the same app build using distinct roots on distinct servers. In my case the [On The Fly](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#on-the-fly) publicPath solves the issue, I just need to tweak the html with a server var replacement and 'fix' my webpack entries.

My entries are like this, the fix should be first thing loaded:

```
entry : {
    entryfile: [ "./fix-public-path.js", "./entryfile.js" ];
}
```

./fix-public-path.js has this content:

```
if (window.__PUBLIC_PATH__) {
  __webpack_public_path__ = window.__PUBLIC_PATH__; // eslint-disable-line
}
```

And my index file has this as the first script on the file:

```
<script>
    __PUBLIC_PATH__ = "@SERVER_SIDE_PUBLIC_PATH@";
</script>
```

Never tested replacing @SERVER_SIDE_PUBLIC_PATH@ with cdn urls, but I think it would work.

Comment: The only problem with this approach for me is that again you are using global variables. I would like to load more applications and for that need to be able to pass each of them a different public path.

Comment: Yes, it is a global variable, but it is does not have to be set on build or in a js code. As you said "I can live with the fact that I will have to manually update all urls in index.html", so you just need to update one more value in your index.html. You can use multiple distinct html files pointing to same bundle.

Comment: You would like to load the same bundle, multiple times on the same environment? Like opening side to side? Or something like "closing" an app and "opening" another one by unloading and loading more bundes on the same page?

Comment: Microsoft made a plugin that could work for you: https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack/tree/master/webpack/set-webpack-public-path-plugin